# Blender 2.79b on a iMac 27 late 2013 with NVIDIA Geforce GTX 780M

Tags: rendering, opengl, osx

I downloaded Blender 2.79b and i am very excited about it. Until... i read about the rendering on a mac and that apple is not supporting Open GL anymore? This is the mac i have: iMac 27 late 2013 with NVIDIA Geforce GTX 780M - 4096 MB, 3,5 GHz Intel i7 and 16GB memory. As i am a noob with 3D (but very excited and love learning it) i am a COMPLETE noob when it comes to render time, Metal, OpenGL and stuff like that. I am reading it online and find it quite difficult to understand it all. My question is this: is blender 2.79b on my Imac (see specs above) enough for someone who has to learn it all (for the next... months? year?) and when i create 'something' in Blender (no animations, just images) can i render it properly? Maybe these are stupid questions but i hope someone can answer them. Thank you. Kind Regards, Mark.

Comment: The specs seems more than sufficient to run Blender smoothly, and render quickly. OpenGL has nothing to do with rendering, it's used to display your scene inside Blender, before rendering (when you're working on it).

Comment: @thibsert Thank you so much for the information. That gives me a good feeling about it. I don't know much about OpenGL. Read some more about it today and i get it now. For a noob like me when it comes to 3D, i can learn enough about Blender by doing it a lot! And it's very nice to know that my machine is more than capable of doint just so. Again, thanks for your info. Greetings Mark